# WPF Binding syntax

Tags: c#, wpf, syntax, binding, path

When to use "/" symbol in path?
I thought "/" uses only when we work with XML, but today see example:

```
class ViewModel
{
    CollectionView Data {get;set;}
}

class BusinessObkect
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}
```

DataContext property of the window is set to an instance of the ViewModel class, Data property of the ViewModel instance is niitialized with a collection of BusinessObject objects.

if Text property of TextBox instance 
`{Binding Path=Data/Name}` all works normal, but if `Text = {Binding Path=Data.Name}` - binding error.

When I must use "/" instead of "." in bindings Path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not ask [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx):

> Subproperties of a property can be specified by a syntax similar to that used in C#. For instance, the clause Path=ShoppingCart.Order sets the binding to the subproperty Order of the object or property ShoppingCart.

> When the source is a [collection view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx), the current item can be specified with a slash (/). For example, the clause Path=/ sets the binding to the current item in the view. When the source is a collection, this syntax specifies the current item of the default collection view.

*(Collection view link added for convenience)*

That's about as concise and complete as it gets. Using `.` notation with a collection to a property of one of its items does not even make sense. e.g. `Collection.Date` as opposed to `Collection/Date` (unless the collection itself actually has a `Date` property for some reason).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use it when `Data` is a collection. `/` takes the current element of the `Data` collection and returns the `Name` property on it.

Comment: What do you mean by the "current element of [a] collection"?  None of the collection types that I am familiar with have a concept of a current item in and of themselves.

Comment: In this case, he uses a `CollectionView` on its own, it already has that. If you use an `ObservableCollection<T>` (or similar), the WPF engine wraps it into a `CollectionView` to supply this necessary infrastructure.